# Slowness of Netbeans Platform Apps - how to mitigate?

Tags: netbeans-platform

We are developing a commerical application (pretty complex) in java using Netbeans IDE. We have 2 options in netbeans to create it-
1. Develop Java desktop app
2. Netbeans Platform app

We have requirement that application startup and response times should be very very fast, should be modular etc. We did Proof of Technology by creating apps using both approaches mentioned above. We found Netbeans platform apps are very slow during startup and during screen navigation compared to pure Swing based desktop apps. We tried to implement suggestions provided at http://wiki.netbeans.org/Category:Performance:FAQ and in other blogs and forums to improve on speed of the app but were not successful.

We feel for creating a complex desktop app Netbeans platform app would be better suited, but its not meeting our performance requirements (startup and response times, memory footprints, CPU usage guidelines etc).

Can any one guide us on how to mitigate our problem of improving performance of Netbeans Platforms apps?

Thanks in advance for your help.

-bhan

Comment: Consider the mono project as well [Not blaming on Java, tho], maybe you can get better results with it and C# aint so different from Java as well :)

Comment: If you don't find a NetBeans Platform evangelist here on SO to help you out, you might try cold-calling (cold-e-mailing?) some of the organizations listed on NetBeans.org's [showcase](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/showcase.html) page, and see if any of them can give you some insight. There are probably a lot more NetBeans IDE PowerUsers on here as compared to NetBeans Platform Wizards.

Comment: First of all what is the definition of very very fast? Can we put some seconds for being very very fast. Second, now a days who is developing this "complex desktop application". If your desktop application has to run on multiple OSs then why not to develop web application? And if it has to run only on say Windows then your choice should be WinForms or MFC. A nicely done web app can also satisfy your performance requirements. SO itself is an example.

Comment: Fast means response times < 150 milliseconds for screen navigation and application startup times < 1 second. Application is for desktop users similar to acrobat reader or MS office and has to run locally on users PC in offline mode only.

Answer (score 0):

Some may not think this is an 'answer' but it is what you will need to do...

1. Engage the community that NetBeans developers have established for these types of questions. See http://netbeans.org/community/lists/top.html... I would recommend that you subscribe to dev@platform.netbeans.org and start asking specific questions about the platform there.  You can read through the archive here: http://netbeans.org/projects/platform/lists/dev/archive
2. File issues that include enough detail for someone to attempt to replicate your results or include sample projects that will let someone focus on the problem that you have encountered.